# Calculate the value of a single text element

Tags: javascript, jquery, eval

I wrote this. But it is using the evil eval. Any guidance on cleaner way to get this done. Is my sanitize method good enough? I searched stack and found other answers but nothing jumped out at me as the **right way**.

```
<input class="simple-math" name="TheCalculation" value="">
```

The end user would enter in *5 + 3* or something and the box would update the value to 8.

```
    $().ready(function () {
        $(".simple-math").change(function () {
            // get the current val
            var raw = $(this).val();
            // sanitize, so a smarty-pants can't do bad stuff
            var sanitize = raw.replace(/[^0-9\+\-\*\/\%\(\)]+/, "");
            // eval the input
            var calc = eval(sanitize);
            // set the value
            $(this).val(calc);
        })
    });
```

Comment: Usually `eval` is evil if you're outputting user-entered data from the server. If you're just `eval`ing what the user enters, what "bad stuff" would they do to themselves?

Comment: @Tesserex very well explained.

Comment: I don't see any dependency on jQuery here that is related to the question.

Comment: Pretty much looking for a sanity check. typically if I use `eval()` I try to find a better way. Seems like it is good enough.

Answer (score 0):

> Cleaner

In what sense? There are some alternatives:

1. Parse the input and do your own calculation, but *eval* pretty much does that for you.
2. Provide a calculator–like UI so the user only has access to tokens you provide to build the expression. Validate the expression as it's built, then pass the result to *eval* (or parse it yourself).

> sanitize method good enough

It will affect the result of expressions like `2.5 * 3` as it will strip the period, and `2.3e3 * 6` where it will strip out the period and `e`, so maybe not.